# С помощью чего делают такой переход?

Tags: php, html, css, css3, html5

https://www.igromania.ru/games/
Там есть переход на другие страницы с играми.

```
1 вопрос: Получается эти страницы - это отдельные папки же?
2 вопрос: Минимальная загрузка происходит благодаря php с помощью include?
```

Comment: эти страницы - это файлы. Возможно это php файлы. А могли это сделать и на `node.js` или `Django/Flask` на Python, или на каком либо ещё серверном языке программирования

Comment: Что такое "минимальная загрузка"?

Comment: barba.js  - типа ajax о котором думать не надо

Comment: А на счёт первого вопроса можно узнать?) Как написал человек выше, это просто отдельные папки со страницами, которые хранятся в папке games и уже в этих папках, которые в games, хранится index.html. ...games/all/2(вторая страница) ...games/all/3(третья страница) и т.д. Правильно ли понимаю?)